# Careers group work experience by company tenure

Tags: feature-request, jobs

It would be useful to have a higher level of grouping for experience entries, what I'm loosely calling "company tenure", especially on the PDF export. If you've worked in multiple positions at the same company or (worse yet) worked at at a company that was acquired by another, the resume looks the same as a "job hopper" at first glance.

Something like this might make the work history more clear:

- **Big Fish Inc and acquired company Small Fish Inc: May 2008-present**

  - Manager of Shoestring Retipping, *Big Fish Inc*: Jun 2010-present
  - Senior Shoestring Analyst, *Big Fish*: Jan 2009-Jun 2010
  - Shoestring Analyst, *Small Fish Inc*: May 2008-Jan 2009
- **Foo Corp : Oct 2004-May 2008**

  - Analyst

Yes, companies truly interested in good employees should look more carefully, but we all know that resumes get thrown out in the initial review by first impressions based on brief looks.

Comment: This would be lovely; (and [recommended on the Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7575/implications-of-showing-promotions-on-cv)!). I wish I could upvote more for _"Manager of Shoestring Retipping"_.

Comment: I ran into this issue just recently plus one

Comment: My last job before my current position was like this - I had 3 different positions with 2 different companies (both owned by the same parent company) and 2 of which I worked in parallel with both companies.  It looked like I had only worked for the company for 6 months, but I'd actually been there for 7 years.

Answer (score 3):

What I do it use the latest position as the main header and then detail past positions, within the same company, in the details section.
[image]

Comment: this is an OK workaround, but not ideal. I think people do want to see the real dates for each position, but what I'm suggesting is a built-in way to do it without looking like a job-hopper on visual scan.

Comment: and a bigger issue is that the technology tags are per-position, so you quickly hit the limit if you try to combine tags from multiple positions (especially spanning merger/acquisition) into one "container" position.